# How can I use Reactive Cocoa in swift4.0

Tags: ios, swift4, reactive-cocoa, rx-swift

I want to build a new project in *swift4.0*,and I'd prefer using Reactive Cocoa.But,*ReactiveCocoa 6.0* would not declare official support *swift4.0*.Is There some other way to solve this problem?Thanks.

Comment: I presume, waiting for the official support would be the solution...?

Answer (score 3):

Fear not, you can freely use ReactiveCocoa 6.x.x with Swift 4.
It works fine with Swift 4. I am using it in several Swift 4 projects.

`pod 'ReactiveCocoa', '~> 7.0.0'` is also available. I think it would be better to start with 7.